# "Arithmetic operation resulted in overflow" in Me.Invoke with multithreading

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, overflow

I have this script:

```
    Private Sub WebDL_AmountDownloadedChanged(ByVal iNewProgress As Long) Handles WebDL.AmountDownloadedChanged
    'On Error Resume Next
    If downloading Then
        Dim wbchanged As New WDL_AmountDownloadedChanged(AddressOf WebDLAmountChanged)
        Me.Invoke(wbchanged, New Object() {CLng(iNewProgress)})
    End If
End Sub
```

During execution, the sub receives into iNewProgress this value: , which results in overflow:

System.OverflowException was unhandled
  Message="Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow."
  Source="System.Windows.Forms"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post the code for you WebDLAmountChanged method.  But the error message says its argument should have been declare As Long but isn't.  Fix:

```
Private Sub WebDLAmountChanged(ByVal progress As Long)
  ' etc...
End Sub
```